# Tracking log block movement using Extended Events

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

If we try to track the log block movement between 2 sync commit replicas,  why do we need to track the immediate next Log block ID in extended events like `hadr_send_harden_lsn`_message on secondary  and `hadr_receive_harden_lsn_message` on primary to track the complete flow of log block until acknowledgement on `hadr_db_commit_mgr_harden` extended event? Also what are the immediate next log block IDs and how do we track them?

Reference:

- [Troubleshooting High HADR_SYNC_COMMIT wait type with Always On
  Availability Groups](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/troubleshooting-high-hadr_sync_commit-wait-type-with-always-on-availability-groups/)